# React: Multiple instances of same Component

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have a situation where I am reusing same component twice. So I have this component "Component A" on the main page, which also contains a button which would open another Dialog which again contains same component "Component A". But the issue here is clicking on the button just reloads the main page doesn't display the dialog with 2nd component "component A". Adding key doesn't seem to help.

Adding Component structure for reference.

[image]

```
//1st component
<ComponentA
  key="1"></ComponentA>

//2nd component (i.e.Dialog)
<Dialog>
...
<ComponentA
  key="2"></ComponentA>
...
</Dialog>
```

Comment: Is the Dialog a Modal? Does it open when you do not have ComponentA in there?

Comment: Please provide a full reproducible example [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @R.Kohlisch Dialog is the child of another component whose parent is the main container. Clicking on the button would set open property of dialog to true.

Comment: Sure, but when you remove `ComponentA` as a child from the `Dialog`, does the Dialog work then?

Comment: @R.Kohlisch Yes. It does. it doesn't display the dialog only when the same Component A is part of it.